# Insert a thousand separator (comma) while typing in NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a property for NumericUpDown called ThousandsSeparator which adds comma once we are done typing and press any key to leave the control.

Is there any other property which can add ThousandsSeparator while the user is still typing?

Comment: MaskedTextBox? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like the OnTextChanged?

Comment: `txtBox.onChange()`?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

The `ThousandsSeparator` property will work either when the user leaves the control, or if the user uses the Up and Down buttons to change the value.

It will not insert the separator while the user is typing because that would be a bad user experience - inserting and removing characters while the user is typing in the control is disconcerting for the user and could lead to an incorrect value being input (for example if the user does a backspace then a left arrow but the backspace has removed the separator between the two keypresses, then the cursor may not be in the expected position).

You might be able to hack something together manually, if you're not concerned about those issues, but if the control value can be in the thousands and the user is typing the value, you might ask the question whether the `NumericUpDown` control is the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use the KeyPress Event Like this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        numericUpDown1.Select();
        SendKeys.Send("{END}");
    }
}
```